# Factor analysis with scale variables

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

First time researching database with scaled data, and looking for a helpful hand, a searchword, or a litterature recommendation.

A sample group of 800+ participants. Goal X is made on the basis of variable 1, 2, 3, and 4, all variables are measured on a scale of 1-10. The Outcome of Goal X is also measured on a scale of 1-10. Variable 4 is re-measured when Outcome of Goal X is measured.

How do I:

1. Statistically analyse the individual variables' effect on the Outcome of Goal X,
2. compare the results of 1. between the variables.
3. statistically analyse the effect of 'the difference in first and second measuring of variable 4' on 'the Outcome of Goal X'?

Thank you for any time you're willing to lend.